# How to select a button which has a certain class name and a unique "name" attribute in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a comment system. In this comment system, when a user a posts a reply to a comment, I wish to display a button called toggle replies - but this is only if it doesn't already possess replies that is. If there are already replies to the comment, then I don't want to hide the replies toggle button.

This button has althe class `.repliestogglebutton`, and has a name which is the same as the comment id of the comment to which the reply is being posted.

This is the html for the button:

```
'<button class="repliestogglebutton" name="'.$commentId.'" style="display:none">toggle all replies</button>';
```

What can I use to select it and toggle it in jQuery? I'm writing this in the success function in my ajax that I'm using to post the reply.

Comment: Pls post a sample code of the jQuery you've written..

Comment: You can use attribute value selector `$(".repliestogglebutton[name='.$commentId.']")`

Comment: I would give it an id and make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you very much all...@Satpal, it worked..that was exactly what I was looking for ..thanks a lot!

Comment: you can also try $("button.repliestogglebutton[name='.$commentId.']")

Comment: @Satpal I'm confused! He has a php variable `$commentId` and the line of code he posted is obviously a `php` string. So he has concatenated his variable with "." But you have a JavaScript string in your sample. Can you please elaborate what does `name='.$commentId.'` exactly means in JavaScript?!

Comment: @EhsanT, Its actually simple. PHP developers generally use jQuery statement in php files,  so `'.$commentId.'` will be modified by PHP engine to something like `name='EhsanT'`

Comment: @Satpal, Actually I did not find it that simple! In that case You either should use `$(".repliestogglebutton[name='<?php echo $commentId;?>']")` if you assume the jquery code is not inside a php tag. or if you assume it is in a php tag, then you should use `'$(".repliestogglebutton[name='.$commentId.']")';` as he has enclosed all of his string in single quote!

Comment: @EhsanT, My bad, actaully it will be interpreted as `$(".repliestogglebutton[name=EhsanT]")'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".repliestogglebutton[name='.$commentId.']")
```

Comment: Really? it worked? Are you sure? Even with the syntax error of concatenation with "." instead of "+" in JavaScript?!?